# My .slidedown() function doesnot work properly in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

Hi I am slicing the objects in an array to show me only 12 objects. But when I try to load more objects, it doesnt slide properly, it slides down but the shown object disappears. Below is my code of a section that has a problem in a class component. In the same section I am trying to shuffle the objects based on there categories. I have given my shuffle and load more methods below. When I comment out the shuffle code it works properly. Please help.

component:

```
<section className="explore-area load-more">
                <div className="container ">
                    <div className="row justify-content-center">
                        <div className="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-7">
                            {/* Intro */}
                            <div className="intro text-center mb-4">
                                <span>{this.state.initData.pre_heading}</span>
                                <h3 className="mt-3 mb-0">{this.state.initData.heading}</h3>
                                <p>{this.state.initData.content}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row justify-content-center text-center">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            {/* Explore Menu */}
                            <div className="explore-menu btn-group btn-group-toggle flex-wrap justify-content-center text-center mb-4" data-toggle="buttons">
                                <label className="btn active d-table text-uppercase p-2">
                                    <input type="radio" defaultValue="all" defaultChecked className="explore-btn" />
                                    <span>{this.state.initData.filter_1}</span>
                                </label>
                                <label className="btn d-table text-uppercase p-2">
                                    <input type="radio" defaultValue="art" className="explore-btn" />
                                    <span>{this.state.initData.filter_2}</span>
                                </label>
                                <label className="btn d-table text-uppercase p-2">
                                    <input type="radio" defaultValue="music" className="explore-btn" />
                                    <span>{this.state.initData.filter_3}</span>
                                </label>
                                <label className="btn d-table text-uppercase p-2">
                                    <input type="radio" defaultValue="collectibles" className="explore-btn" />
                                    <span>{this.state.initData.filter_4}</span>
                                </label>
                                <label className="btn d-table text-uppercase p-2">
                                    <input type="radio" defaultValue="sports" className="explore-btn" />
                                    <span>{this.state.initData.filter_5}</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row items explore-items ">
                        {this.state.data.map((item, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={`edth_${idx}`} className="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 explore-item item" data-groups={item.group}>
                                    <div className="card">
                                        <div className="image-over">
                                            <a href="/item-details">
                                                <img className="card-img-top" src={item.img} alt="" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        {/* Card Caption */}
                                        <div className="card-caption col-12 p-0 ">
                                            {/* Card Body */}
                                            <div className="card-body">
                                                <a href="/item-details">
                                                    <h5 className="mb-0">{item.title}</h5>
                                                </a>
                                                <div className="seller d-flex align-items-center my-3">
                                                    <span>Owned By</span>
                                                    <a href="/author">
                                                        <h6 className="ml-2 mb-0">{item.owner}</h6>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="card-bottom d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                    <span>{item.price}</span>
                                                    <span>{item.count}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <a className="btn btn-bordered-white btn-smaller mt-3" href="/wallet-connect"><i className="icon-handbag mr-2" />{item.btnText}</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <div className="row ">
                        <div className="col-12 text-center">
                            <a id="load-btn" className="btn btn-bordered-white mt-5" >{this.state.initData.btnText}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </section> 

   /*----------------------------------------------
    5. Load More
    ----------------------------------------------*/
    (function ($) {

        'use strict';

        $(".load-more .item").slice(0, 12).show();

        $("#load-btn").on('click', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $(".load-more .item:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();

            if ($(".load-more .item:hidden").length == 0) {
                $("#load-btn").fadeOut('slow');
            }

        });
    }(jQuery));

    /*----------------------------------------------
    6. Shuffle
    ----------------------------------------------*/
    (function ($) {

        'use strict';

        $('.explore-area').each(function(index) {

            var count = index + 1;

            $(this).find('.explore-items').removeClass('explore-items').addClass('explore-items-'+count);
            $(this).find('.explore-item').removeClass('explore-item').addClass('explore-item-'+count);
            $(this).find('.explore-btn').removeClass('explore-btn').addClass('explore-btn-'+count);
            
            var Shuffle = window.Shuffle;
            var Filter  = new Shuffle(document.querySelector('.explore-items-'+count), {
                itemSelector: '.explore-item-'+count,
                buffer: 1,
            })

            $('.explore-btn-'+count).on('change', function (e) {

                var input = e.currentTarget;
                
                if (input.checked) {
                    Filter.filter(input.value);
                }
            })
        });

    }(jQuery));
```